# How to check a list of email ids and remove the ones that are gibberish/upper case using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a json file and I extract a list of email ids - specifically two lists(spam and legitimate emails) but within these lists, I'd like to eliminate email ids that are upper-case, numerical etc. How can I leave those out of the list?

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    json_decode = json.loads(fp.read())
    line = str(json_decode)

    # find all emails
    match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w.-]+', line)

    legit = []
    spam = []

    for email in match:
        email_status = email.endswith("gmail.com")
        if email_status == False:
            spam.append(email)
        else:
```

OUTPUT:

```
     The legit list is {'taylor.l@gmail.com', '6ca63336ba8b483ca5f543cbad585fbb@gmail.com', 'Taylor.L@gmail.gov', 'abuse@gmail.com'} I want only one element - {'taylor.l@gmail.com'} and it's not always the first element in the list.

      The spam list is {'n@TENT...', 'arealjcl@countable.us', 'image001.png@01D36CD8.2A2219D0', 'e8a1fdc83d13a56f4dbffdeb5942eba0@pisicano.cf'} and I want to remove everything except {'arealjcl@countable.us'}
```

How can I use regex to come up with a condition to eliminate the email ids I don't need?

Comment: Please be a bit more precise. You do not want the emails to contain any digit (what about `tayloer.l123@gmail.com`) and want to ignore emails starting with an uppercase letter?

Comment: @Jan Yes you have a point - I cannot eliminate emails that contain digits. `tayloer.l123@gmail.com` is a valid one so not sure how to factor that when I define a rule. I'm confused too - I guess I can eliminate emails that have a digit or upper case letter in their domain name `@01D36CD8` etc

Comment: Sorry you can't eliminate domain names with digits in them `bet365.com` is a valid domain name.

Comment: @JGNI oops so what's the best option here? any clue?

Comment: Read this, https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/, then take a look at https://regex101.com/r/31plIS/5 which is the current version of a regex I wrote to parse a list of valid email addresses